# Is the data always available with a Rename in Redis?

Tags: redis

When I run a rename command, I think it does something like this,

1. Use new name for new data
2. remove reference for old name
3. remove old data (this can take some time if it’s large)

For clients accessing this data, is there ever a time where any of these happen?

1. The key does not exist
2. The data is not in a good state
3. Redis hangs during access

What steps are performed during a Redis rename command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Redis has single threaded execution of commands, the rename will be atomic, so the answer to 1 and 2 are no. The thing about it "removing old data" is only if the destination key already points to a large structure that it needs to delete (Redis will clobber it.) The original data object will not be copied. Only hash table entries pointing to it might be moved around. Since rehashing in Redis is incremental, this should essentially be constant time.

Redis will always "hang" on slow commands due to the single threaded command execution. So for 3, it can always be yes depending on what you're doing, but in this case, only if you're doing significantly large implicit delete.

Edit: as of Redis 4.0 you can actually specify the config option `lazyfree-lazy-server-del yes` (default is `no`) and the server will actually delete asynchronously for side-effect deletes such as this. In other words, instead of delete blocking, the object will be queued for background deletion. This would effectively make `RENAME` constant time. See sample cfg: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf